# Match any nine digit number surrounded by word boundaries, but not those preceded by a period

Tags: regex

Have a pretty specific Regex I need help building. Some restrictions: can't be multi-line, and uses the Go engine so it can't use negative lookbehinds.

```
Match any nine digit number surrounded by word boundaries, but not those preceded by a period.

123456789  Should match
 123456789  Should match
123456789. Should match

0.123456789  Should not match
.123456789  Should not match
```

https://regex101.com/r/aAd7nN/1

So far I have `\b\d{9}\b`, but as you'll see in the Regex101 example, it doesn't work when there's a preceding period.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using an alternation with a capturing group `\.\d{9}\b|\b(\d{9})\b` where you match the  digit preceded by a dot, and keep the 9 digits in the capturing group https://regex101.com/r/LDOniG/1

Comment: Some believe that life is not worth living without negative lookbehinds. Some of those believe that life is not worth living without variable-length negative lookbehinds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also use:

```
(?:^|\n|[^.])\b(\d{9})\b
```

and grab capture group #1 for your match.

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aAd7nN/2)

Answer (score 3):

You could match what you don't want and capture in a group what you want to keep using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`

```
\.\d{9}\b|\b(\d{9})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LDOniG/1)

Comment: Clever! It also works with "0.123456789 123456789".